# C GtkTreeModel/Store memory release

Tags: c, gtk

for example:
i create and fill with strings such structure:

- `GtkTreeStore *store = gtk_tree_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);`

and then in some place in code i invoke

- `g_object_unref(store);`

After that strings stored in `store` would be freed or not? If not, how to properly release memory from `GtkTreeStore` or `GtkTreeModel`?

Documentation say nothing about that. (or i cant find info :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not explicit but the documentation is still pretty clear: see [gtk_tree_store_set()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeStore.html#gtk-tree-store-set):

> The value will be referenced by the store if it is a G_TYPE_OBJECT,
>   and it will be copied if it is a G_TYPE_STRING or G_TYPE_BOXED.

So GtkTreeStore will do its own memory management. In practice you can free your string as soon as you've called `gtk_tree_store_set*()` (or  `gtk_tree_store_insert_with_values*()`) with it: at that point the tree store has already made a copy of the string.